# Why are there no new major aircraft in ICAO Aerodrome catagory D?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, icao

So the 757, 767, A300 and A310 all were in ICAO cat D (mainly restricted by a wingspan between 36-less than 52m). Now though all these aircraft are discontinued, and there is no new designs looking to directly replace them. I’d love to know why this is, whether there are still gates for D class aircraft and whether aircraft such as the A321neo could start to make a business case for Airbus’ replacement for the A320 family to go up an ICAO catagory in exchange for a big fuel efficiency improvement?

Comment: If the question revolves around "why" the answer is probably "money."

Comment: Don't know for sure, but I'd say as Zeiss says, it's getting harder and harder to raise capital for that kind of project. The C Series nearly bankrupted Bombardier, and they were forced to give it away to Airbus for free.  Ever since the 2008 crisis, banks have been much more risk averse than before it and risk capital has been harder to raise.

Comment: That’s a good (if slightly depressing) point. I guess Airbus will do a lot of cringing over any new designs from now on. Of course, once you commit to making a new design you are already taking a massive capital risk